# prettyphoto plugin not playing videos of vzaar

Tags: video, prettyphoto

I've added prettyphoto plugin to my website to play videos on a popup. Videos on youtube and vimeo are working great but the videos on vzaar are not. I'm getting this error : "Image cannot be loaded. Make sure the path is correct and image exist."

Is there anyone who knows a solution for this or any better offer for playing vzaar videos on a popup?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I should point out first of all that we have a customer support forum at http://vzaar.com/help, so you'll be able to get a fast, accurate response from us in the event of any future problems you might encounter.

Regarding your current issue, though: could you provide your code or a link to the site so we can distinguish what the problem is?

Alternatively, there is a tutorial in our knowledge base to achieve this effect using zoombox, which you can find here: http://vzaar.com/help/kb/video-and-technical-questions/how-do-i-create-a-video-lightbox

All the best,
Dan